# Some questions about a proper or perfect map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, a function $f : X → Y$ between two topological spaces is proper if the preimage of every compact set in $Y$ is compact in $X$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $f$ be a map from $X$ to $Y$ that is continuous, closed, surjective and such that $f^−1(y)$ is compact relative to $X$ for each $y$ in $Y$. Then $f$ is called a perfect map.

1.Can you give a map $f$ such that $f$ is a continuous map, $f^{−1}(y)$ is compact relative to $X$ for each $y$ in $Y$, but $f$ is not a proper map?

2.If $f: X→Y$ is a perfect map and $X$ is regular, then $Y$ is regular.

3.If $f: X → Y$ is a perfect map and if $X$ is second countable, then $Y$ is second countable.

How to prove it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints:

1. Note that every finite set is compact. What is the simplest function $f:X\to Y$ you can think of (where $X$ and $Y$ are sets of your choice) such that its fibers are finite. Can you further find topologies on $X$ and $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous but not proper.
2. Let $f:X\to Y$ be perfect map. Define 
   $$f_\forall(A)=\{y\in Y\mid f^{-1}(y)\subseteq A\}$$
   It is easy to show that $f_\forall (A)=Y\setminus f(X\setminus A)$. Since $f$ is closed, $f_\forall$ sends open subsets of $X$ to open sets in $Y$. Since $f_\forall$ preserves intersections, it sends disjoint open sets to disjoint open sets in $Y$, so it suffices to find for any closed set $B\subset Y$ and any point $y\in Y\setminus B$ disjoint neighborhoods about $f^{-1}(y)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$.
3. Assume $\mathcal B = \{B_1,B_2,\dots\}$ is the countable base of $X$. For any finite subset $F$ of $\mathbb N$, define
   $$
   \textstyle
   B_F = f_\forall\left(\bigcup_{f\in F}B_f\right)
   $$
   Can you show that the family of all these sets form a countable basis for $Y$?